# Where can I find HTML in ASP.NET project?

Tags: html, asp.net, solution

Today I got an assignment to work on a certain webpage. I am a bit new to ASP.NET so I was wondering if anyone could tell me where I can find the file generating HTML code in an already existing ASP.NET solution? The .aspx or .html/.htm files were not provided in the solution

Edit: The use of webparts fixed the problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Did your instructor for this assignment point you to any documentation whatsoever? What did you try and find?

Comment: Please provide us which ASP.NET, WebForms, MVC, or WebPages?

Answer (score 0):

Look for files with the extension .aspx, they'll be the markup files.

Answer (score 0):

They will either be in your views folder if it is an mvc project, or be files in your solution with .aspx extension.

Comment: That's the problem, there is no .aspx file available, so I have been searching and found out webparts have been used with html content inside. However one of the few files provided was a stylesheet. With that I could fix my problem.